# Where to start tracing down an exception?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm getting an exception in production which isn't providing and stacktrace information. How do I start debugging where this might be coming from?

```
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: Exception: RedisError: Disconnected (Redis::DisconnectedError) 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x4af6ac: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x4ce900: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x4b553e: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x529d1c: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x518cb2: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x518064: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x521d82: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x51ed3b: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x5240e9: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x50b995: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x416209: ??? at ?? 
Oct 25 16:26:17 socket-proxy app/web.1: 0x0: ??? at ??
```

Comment: Are you compiling with `--no-debug`?

Comment: @RX14 that was a good lead. I'm using the Heroku buildpack which seems to compile with `--no-debug`. I'll try w/o that flag and hopefully get a better stack trace.

Comment: I tried turning off of `--no-debug` with a PR to the heroku buildpack, but run into compile issues. 

https://github.com/crystal-lang/heroku-buildpack-crystal/pull/26
https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4719

Comment: Yeah you should instead send a PR to attempt a non-release build, as --release currently requires --no-debug. Without release its still very fast so don't worry.

Comment: I'll update the PR, thanks @RX14

Answer (score 4):

Ruby dev here so not sure why stack trace is printed mysteriously, however if you are looking for some clues as to where to look I would start at this class:

[redis/error.cr](https://github.com/stefanwille/crystal-redis/blob/master/src/redis/error.cr)

```
# Exception for errors that Redis returns.
class Redis::Error < Exception
  def initialize(s)
    super("RedisError: #{s}")
  end
end

class Redis::DisconnectedError < Redis::Error
  def initialize
    super("Disconnected")
  end
end
```

Now clearly only place that exception seems to being raised in the [crystal-redis](https://github.com/stefanwille/crystal-redis) repository is in this class:

[redis/connection.cr (line:  )](https://github.com/stefanwille/crystal-redis/blob/fd5bc7aa9965a5d2c02328310707186405f9d935/src/redis/connection.cr#L118)

```
def receive_line
    line = @socket.gets(chomp: false)
    unless line
      raise Redis::DisconnectedError.new
    end
    line.byte_slice(0, line.bytesize - 2)
end
```

Looking at the method that uses it, `receive_line` it seems the error is clearly being thrown at `Redis::Connection` during connection or `receive` method.

So either its a error during connection, or a dropped connection.

Considering the clueless stack-trace, that would be a good start, unless you can share some more code to look at.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being because of the production server timing out the redis connection after a period of time. I've switched to `redis-reconnect` to auto-reconnect.

https://github.com/danielwestendorf/redis-reconnect